# Custom Hook causes for a PCP problems on event registration page

Tags: hooks, pcp, personal-campaign-pages

I have a custom function written to show the name of the contribution page that a PCP is a part of. After some help from the community, I got it working, hooray! 
[Trying to write a hook to add contribution page name to Main.tpl I'm super close](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2856/trying-to-write-a-hook-to-add-contribution-page-name-to-main-tpl-im-super-close)

But on my event registration links (not contribution pages, oddly enough) or PCP creation links - I get the following error 'CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "Expected one ContributionPage but found 25"' (I have a total of 25 contribution pages set up so I can see why it says it finds 25 but why it's looking in the first place I'm not sure.

Here is the final code I'm using

```
function wordpress_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
    $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
    if ( $config->userFrameworkFrontend ) {

          $page = civicrm_api3('contribution_page', 'getsingle', array(
            'id' => $form->_id,
            'check_permissions' => FALSE,
            'return' => 'title',
          ));
          $form->assign('cPageName', $page['title']);

    }
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your hook is executing unconditionally on every form. To target just the contribution form, the first line inside your function should be `if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main') {`.